# How could I share my project without installation of any dependances?

Tags: linux, compilation, ogre, cegui

I have some question about the sharing of a project in Linux.
I have an Ogre game that I would like to share with other people, without any installation of dependances.
First, is it possible to just compile the binary, and share it with other people?

If not,is it possible to compile the project with the .so libs I got from the Fedora repository ?

Comment: you should try to use docker, install all the dependencies within a container build an image and share it with other people, the only requirement is to have docker installed and run the image.

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=83018